# SSH - remote address to local IP

Tags: ssh

At start, sorry for my english.

I have remote computer without IP (only no-ip address) with http server, mysql etc.
Now with my laptop i want to make connection with the remote PC over SSH and make the remote PC works as like in LAN with my laptop, having own local IP (192.168.1.xxx). Is any way to do this? If not through SSH, then how?

Comment: Have you connected to this remote computer any other way?

Comment: Is the remote system possibly part of a shared hosting solution? What do you mean by "without IP"?

Comment: I tried VPN and hosts file if you're asking for this. Problem is, that remote PC doesn't have static IP, only dynamic. I get no-ip address for this PC and it's accessible from web, but also i want to make it's accessible over domain.com using /etc/hosts file.

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg: No, remote PC is my own PC. By without IP i mean that PC have only dynamic IP and i can not connect with over it.

Comment: Why not ssh to the no-ip hostname every time?  Do you need to access something by IP address?

Comment: @Jim G.: Because i want to "plug" my PC on laptop as virtual domain using windows /etc/hosts, and this method don't allow use no-ip address. And i want to http server on my PC be accessible on laptop, so i need to use SSH with no-ip address to make server from my PC to looks like localhost. But i already done that, ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 my.no-ip.org, so thank you for your help :)